# Classifying Groups of Order 42 with an element of Order 6

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of Order 42 which has an element of order 6. I want to classify all groups like this up to isomorphism.
Let $g\in G$ be the element of order 6. Then $C_6\cong\langle g\rangle\leq G$. As $42=6\cdot 7$ and $6<7$ there is only one 7-Sylow Subgroup, which thus is normal and ismorphic to $C_7$. Let $P$ be this group.
As elements in $P$ have order 7 and elements in $\langle g\rangle$ have order which divides 6, we know that $P\cap \langle g\rangle=\{1\}$.
Now as P is normal, the Frobenius product of P and $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of Order  $$\frac{|P||\langle g\rangle|}{|P\cap \langle g\rangle}=42$$
So we know the Frobenius Product is the whole Group thus the Group is its inner semidirect bewteen P and $\langle g \rangle$.
We know now, that all Groups like this are ismorphic to a group of the form $C_7\rtimes_\varphi C_6$ for an homorphism $\varphi$ bewteen $C_6$ and $Aut(C_7)$ and all Groups that are of this form have $C_6$ as a subgroup and are of order 42.
So we need to find all homorphisms between $C_6$ and $Aut(C_7)$. This is where I'm now stuck a litte bit. How would I go about classifying all those homomorphisms?

Comment: Hint: Aut$(C_n)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: You may need the following fact:
${\rm Aut}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$, where $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is the group \begin{equation*}
\{\bar{k}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: \text{$k$ is coprime with $n$} \},
\end{equation*}
with operation $\cdot$: $\bar{k_1}\cdot\bar{k_2}=\overline{k_1k_2}$. (to be continued)

Comment: (*Sketch of Proof*: Let $\varphi\in {\rm Aut}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\varphi(\bar{1})=\bar{k}$ for some $k$ coprime with $n$, and therefore $\bar{k}\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. Check $\varphi\mapsto \varphi(\bar{1})=\bar{k}$ is the desired isomorphism.)
Check that ${\rm Aut}\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\cong (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^{*}\cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ (The last isomorphism comes from the existence of an element of order $6$).
What are the homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ into itself?

Comment: For the classification see the answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375496/groups-of-order-42-and-classification), for example. For a similar question about $C_6$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470782/isomorphisms-between-groups-of-order-42).